# WebStorm specific file names don't get recognized as TypeScript files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

Upgraded to the last version of WebStorm and files with the name of `actions.ts` don't get recognize as `.ts` files by the IDE. The file open as `.txt` file even though the suffix is still `.ts`.

[image: file icon is as TXT file icon]

[image: plain white text as TXT file and not as TS]

And this issue happens only for files with the name of `actions.ts`, other files get recognized normally.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you make an File Type association by accident, it can be fixed by going to `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `File Types` -> `Text` and removing `actions.ts` using the `-` in the right menu.

Example:
[image]